# Expose variable to the devtools console without making it global on window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Is it possible to make a variable easily accessible by the debug console without actually making it global? For example, something like this in the code:

console.$ = jQuery

And then in the console, I'd like this to work:

$('#foo')

Answer (score 4):

Not while the page isn't paused at a breakpoint, no. But when the page *is* paused at a breakpoint, the console has access to all variables that are in-scope at the point where it's stopped.

Of course, your `console.$ = jQuery` example *does* make it possible to do

```
console.$("#foo")
```

...in the console.

---

Side note: `console.$ = jQuery` and `$("#foo")` aren't *great* examples, as jQuery is almost always global, and even if you don't have jQuery loaded on your page at all, Chrome provides its own `$` function in the console, and I think at least one other browser does as well...